# GKTurnBasedMatch in a new game can i wait until another player has accepted my invitation?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, gamekit

I'm writing the multiplayer part of a turn based game,i'm using game center to manage the matches. Starting a new game with GKTurnBasedMatch do not send immediatly the invite notification to the other player. To send the notification i have to made my move and end first turn... Can i modify this behaviour? I wanna made my first turn only if the other player has already accept my invitation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check the `status` property of the other participant who is of class `GKTurnBasedParticipant`. If its status continues to be `GKTurnBasedParticipantStatusInvited`, forbid yourself from opening the game controller and display an alert.

[GKTurnBasedParticipant documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedParticipant_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKTurnBasedParticipant)

Answer (score 2):

One way of appearing to do this would be to add a value in the NSData, say an int, that remembers what turn number it is.  Start your game, then end your turn immediately without showing anything to the user.  All it does is increments the turn number.  When the other player accepts, if the turn number says its the second turn, increment the turn number again, and end their turn.  Continue this end-increment-end pattern until the first player receives the turn back, then start playing normally, with all players having accepted the invitations and officially joined the game.

I do not recommend doing this, as this can cause a significant delay in the play time for the players who are ready to begin.  They may expect it from your game eventually, but the standard pattern has a shorter apparent waiting time for the players to begin playing.